# Preventing CoD Warzone from switching to windowed mode mid-game

Tags: call-of-duty-warzone

For a while, when I am playing Warzone, CoD switches from full screen to windowed mode. Besides being annoying, that disables my controls for seconds and I have to click on the game to go back to full screen, and only then I gain back controls (same as if you hit the Win key; I have Win key disabled though).

I am sure this is not something that happens due to hitting a key or something since sometimes when I leave my PC and come back to it I see that it is in windowed mode. I disabled all the overlay features from discord and Nvidia. I am on Windows 10 if that matters.

Has anyone had the same problem?